# Отключение клавиатуры по usb на python

Tags: python, cmd, powershell, usb, pywin32

необходимо отключить клавиатуру по usb. Смысл в том что подсветка клавиатуры отключается только горячими клавишами, я пробовал найти кнопку с помощью pyautogui и keyboard, данные библиотеки её не видят. Пк постоянно включен мониторы выключаются бат файлом, звук функцией на python. Хочу добавить в общий скрипт отключение подсветки клавиатуры но не могу понять как это сделать. Сойдёт любое действие которое можно добавить в код на python.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151140/discussion-on-question-by-zoombi-89-adm----usb--python); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.